# Button text not changing when called in viewController init

Tags: swift, uibutton, initialization, viewdidload

I'm trying to change the text of a UIButton based on values that are set in my viewController init.

So here's the init:

```
init(viewModel: ViewModel, stateMachine: StateMachine) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    self.stateMachine = stateMachine
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) 
    title = "TEST"
    setInitialButtonText()
}
```

The button setting method:

```
private func setInitialButtonText() {
    if viewModel.order.measurement.total != nil {
            button.title = "Review"
        } else {
            button.title = "Check"
        }
    }
```

Required values are loaded in viewModel.

Now when I call this button method in this init, it has no effect. Yet when I call it in viewDidLoad, it works.

The button code is as follows:

```
lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(title: "Test", color: UIColor.green)
    button.alpha = 1
    return button
}()

init(@escaping buttonAction) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        stackView.addButtons([button])
        button.pressedAction = buttonAction
    }
```

When I put the method into init, the default initialised value of 'Test' shows on the button. However, when I print the button title from both init and viewDidLoad, first the viewDidLoad one is called and shows 'Test' and later the init one is called and shows the correct value. If this is called after viewDidLoad, why does it not reflect on the UI?

When I insert the method into viewDidLoad, the correct value is displayed...

Sure I'm missing something obvious here but any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I printed from viewDidDisappear as well and the correct value is printing even when I call the method from init. So the property is being set but not displayed on the button...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether that's the problem. But have you tried to set the title of the button by using `button.setTitle("myTitle", for: .normal)`?

Comment: Sadly yes I did :(

Answer (score 0):

None of the code above shows you actually adding the button to the view controller's view - without seeing more it's difficult to tell, but is it possible that you are *also* creating and adding the button in a xib, and assigning it to the `button` property? This would replace the button you have created in the lazy load.

Alternatively, is there a totally separate button that you are creating, but is never getting updated?

How does `button` get added to the view controller's view?

Comment: sorry, added the init for the buttons now - and figured it out in the end so going to post an answer

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've added a new argument to the init as follows:

```
init(@escaping buttonAction, buttonTitle: String) {
        self.buttonTitle = buttonTitle
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        stackView.addButtons([button])
        button.pressedAction = buttonAction
    }
```

Then in the button variable:

```
let button = I6Button(title: reviewFuelSheetButtonTitle, color: UIColor.i6.green)
```

And then finally in the viewController I added a didSet on the viewModel:

```
private var viewModel: ViewModel {
    didSet {
        setInitialButtonText()
    }
}
```